# Failure to reliably overwrite file from VBA

Tags: file, excel, overwrite, vba

I have a VBA program that should delete and overwrite a file, with the same name. Code sample is below. Everything worked fine until maybe several months ago, when the overwrite started behaving strangely despite no apparent change anywhere. At times, the file was not overwritten at all. I then tried deleting the file manually before doing the write from VBA, that also didn't work, instead it looked like the previous version in the recycle bin was being restored, rather than overwriting my new version.

When I manually delete the file in the target folder, and also delete all previous revs from the recycle bin, the write works fine.

Posting this following a lot of googling and other searching, however nothing describes my specific problem. Any suggestions on what's happening here /  how to fix?

Excel 2013 under Win10. Nothing unusual about the platform, the excel setup or the file being written, plenty of disk space available.

```
fname = "C:\DatFolder\Incrdat.bin"
Kill fname   ' remove previous file
fnum = FreeFile
Open fname For Binary Access Write As #fnum

.... do write

Close #fnum
```

### Edit 14 May, following many trials.

OMG how can this be so difficult???  :-/. I've put error checks on all the file ops, none occur. I've also added a 1-sec wait between the Kill and the file create.  What happens now every time, is following the delete and rewrite, there is a file there again, but it's the previous file with the old timestamp. ie. Somehow the file that has been deleted is just put back as it was previously.

When I step through the code in debug, it works fine.

Many thanks for all the suggestions, but none of them have worked. I'm giving up and redoing the whole damn thing in C++, I know that'll work.

One more thing, unfortunately the suggestions to rewrite with a different file name, or to a different folder, can't be used unfortunately.

Comment: What happens if you place `DoEvents` after the `Kill` command?

Comment: Try a different folder, preferrably %appdata%\DatFolder ... or try writing to a new file every time? Try deleting the file first, and then only writing if it has been confirmed that it is deleted? Also maybe try the FileSystemObject instead of Open